# Как правильно распараллелить процесс парсинга?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

В таймере каждые 10-сек делаю запрос на 3 разных сайта. Хочу параллельно запустить эти три запроса и ждать пока они все отработают. Как это правильней всего сделать?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

   aTimer.Interval = 10000;
   if (button1.Text == "Старт") {
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    button1.Text = "Стоп";
   } else {
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    button1.Text = "Старт";

   }

  }

  private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
   Run();
  }
  public void Run() {
   var site1 = getKeys("url1");
   var site2 = getKeys("url2");
   var site3 = getKeys("url3");
   // дальше идут определенные операции с переменными site1,site2 и site3

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый простой и быстрый способ это сделать, это запустить `Task` на каждый запрос:

```
public void Run()
{
  var siteTask1 = Task<IEnumerable<Key>>.Run(() => getKeys("url1"));
  var siteTask2 = Task<IEnumerable<Key>>.Run(() => getKeys("url2"));
  var siteTask3 = Task<IEnumerable<Key>>.Run(() => getKeys("url3"));

  Task.WaitAll(siteTask1, siteTask2, siteTask3);

  var site1 = siteTask1.Result;
  var site2 = siteTask2.Result;
  var site3 = siteTask3.Result;
}
```

В `Task<IEnumerable<Key>>` `IEnumerable<Key>` это тот тип данных корый возвращает метод `getKeys`.

Answer (score 5):

Для распараллеливания задач в .NET существует класс `Parallel`, который является частью [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460717.aspx), a так же [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460688.aspx) – еще более высокоуровневая абстракция.

Используя PLINQ:

```
var urls = new[] { "url1", "url2", "url3" };
var urlsAndKeys = (from url in urls.AsParallel() select new { url, key = getKey(url) }).ToList();
urlsAndKeys.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Если вас пугает PLINQ, можно использовать TPL напрямую:

```
var urls = new[] { "url1", "url2", "url3" };
var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
{
    var key = getKey(url);
    lock (results)
    {
        results.Add(url, key);
    }
});

foreach (var urlAndKey in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"URL: {urlAndKey.Key}, Key: {urlAndKey.Value}");
}
```

Comment: +1, но не стоит вызывать getkey под блокировкой.

Comment: +1, тоже хороший вариант, и +1 про `getKey` в `lock`)

Comment: @VladD точно, исправил.